Download the original picture of LinkedIn Photo Profile 2023
I want to download other person LinkedIn Photo Profile: https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5103AQGIsL8K-cDbXw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1517356831808?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=lwL_S2AGhXEmK0mBL3_ouX9u4OldoB2jc-QchgzAMww
in original size. I try to modify 800_800 in profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800  , but appear the message
Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C5103AQGIsL8K-cDbXw/profile-displayphoto-shrink_1200_800/0/1517356831808?" on this server.

Reference #18.ad2a6276.1696727584.2814966 

Now I try download as this reference: https://aboundsocial.com/how-can-i-download-my-linkedin-profile-photo-full-sized/
I try to inspect element in the LinkedIn Profile in Mozilla Firefox browser, but I can't find link of original picture.
How to download original picture (fullsize picture) of LinkedIn profile?

I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a practical question about using a web application.

I am reviewing deleted closed questions.  I was the one who closed this so I'm adding it to the reopen-review queue to allow the community a chance to do its own review and decide if it should remain closed or be reopened.
